# Скрипт удаления файлов по сети в нескольких источниках

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripts

Подскажите, нужно удалять файлы с определенным разрешением из разных сетевых директорий.
Есть код, который удаляет нужные файлы, но только с одной сетевой директории. Как сделать так, чтобы можно было удалять с нескольких? Допустим с 10 разных адресов?

```
import os

    def main():
        path = "//10.10.8.3/resourse/"
        extension = ".res"
        if os.path.exists(path):
            if os.path.isdir(path):
                for root_folder, folders, files in os.walk(path):
                    for file in files:
                        file_path = os.path.join(root_folder, file)
                        file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]
                        if extension == file_extension:
                            if not os.remove(file_path):
                                print(f"{file_path} deleted successfully")
                            else:
                                print(f"Unable to delete the {file_path}")
            else:
                print(f"{path} is not a directory")
        else:
            print(f"{path} doesn't exist")
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

def main(path):
    extension = ".res"
    if os.path.exists(path):
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            for root_folder, folders, files in os.walk(path):
                for file in files:
                    file_path = os.path.join(root_folder, file)
                    file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_path)[1]
                    if extension == file_extension:
                        if not os.remove(file_path):
                            print(f"{file_path} deleted successfully")
                        else:
                            print(f"Unable to delete the {file_path}")
        else:
            print(f"{path} is not a directory")
    else:
        print(f"{path} doesn't exist")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main("//10.10.8.1/resourse/")
    main("//10.10.8.2/resourse/")
    main("//10.10.8.3/resourse/")
    main("//10.10.8.4/resourse/")
    main("//10.10.8.5/resourse/")
    main("//10.10.8.6/resourse/")
    main("//10.10.8.10/resourse/")
    main("//10.10.8.15/resourse/")
    main("//10.10.8.20/resourse/")
    main("//10.10.8.25/resourse/")
```

Comment: Очень помогли, спасибо!

Comment: Гениально! А если с тысячи адресов надо?

Comment: @strawdog если тысячи для домашеней сети, то это уже будет коммерческое решение ;-)

Comment: @strawdog, какие еще есть варианты? Можете скинуть информацию для изучения, если не трудно. Я только изучаю python, приму любую помощь.

Comment: @aasdt все зависит от входящих данных, у вас один узел или много (у вас есть список узлов (если есть то в каком формате) или надо искать), или возможно вы хотите пройтись по одному узлу во всех поддиректориях.

Comment: @xmokko, Список адресов(устройств) есть, искать не нужно. При желании можно выгрузить в какой-нибудь .txt